# I use a steam of gas to operate - what am I?

Tags: riddle

> I come in several different forms
>
> People can find me annoying
>
> I use a steam of gas to operate
>
> I can be known as a penny *?*

What am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you mean a **stream** of gas (a **steam** of gas makes no sense) my answer is

> **Whistle**
>  
>  There are several types of **whistle**, all operated by a stream of gas.
>  People can find any of them annoying, particularly the 3rd one. 
>  
>  A referee's whistle (with or without a rolling pea).
>  A steam engine's whistle (perhaps this is why you wrote "steam").
>  A sound made by a person's mouth parts (lips or tongue).
>  A sound made by the wind through narrow obstructions. 
>  A tin whistle (a musical instrument) also known as a **penny whistle**.

We get **penny** from the last one.